# how do you refresh and html page from the server every 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html page that displays bunch of charts. This site integrated with a ventor SSO application. You bring the site first time, it goes to the sso authentication and once authenticated, you are into the site.

This vendor SSO middle apps has a 30 minute title timeout session. If a user brings up the site and logs in and stays idle for 30 minutes, the site stops functioning. The user needs to login to the SSO again to use.

My problem is this. If the user logs in and dont use the site for 30 minutes, and if he/she tries to use it again by bringing up the url or refreshing the browser, the page is not doing anything. The browser is not forwarding the page to the SSO login, it is using the browser cache.

To get around it, I wrote this script so that every 15 minute, the page will refresh from the server. Not sure what is wrong but I do see that it works sometimes and times the browser still trying to load the page from the browser cache. Is what I am doing below right? Any other ideas to address this issue?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('div').live('pagehide', function(event, ui){
var page = jQuery(event.target);

if(page.attr('data-cache') == 'never'){
page.remove();
};
});
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 900000);
});
</script>
<script>
```

Comment: Don't use `.live(..)` it is deprecated, use `.on(..)` instead.

Comment: Which server side language are you using? If it's php why not increase the session time if you're using sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a meta-tag in the header instead.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
</head>
```

That's 900 seconds being equal to 15 minutes.

Comment: @Farce, I used the refresh tag but it actualy refeshes but then I get an error saying, the page does not know how to forward to that sso login page?

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message, and perhaps update your original question with it?

Comment: @Farce, there is no error. The page stops working. After I manually clear my cache and cookies, it starts working again.

Comment: @user1471980, if you have the URL for the SSO login page, you could also use: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900; url=http://www.example.com/your_sso_login_page">` so that users are redirected to the login page, instead of to the page they were originally viewing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout('window.location.reload();', 90000);
    // OR
   // setTimeout('location.reload(true);', 5000);   

  jQuery('div').live('pagehide', function(event, ui){
     var page = jQuery(event.target);

      if(page.attr('data-cache') == 'never'){
            page.remove();
      }
  });

});
```

Also, I won't recommend using `live`

Comment: how do I use the setTimeout?

Comment: I have it like this, does not seem to be working.<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout('location.reload(true);', 5000);
</script>

Comment: Check updated answer. Place all your code below setimeout. The reason I am saying this is because if there is an error in your js code, the setimeout functiion won't execute

Answer (score 0):

You should instead just send an ajax request to a page on the server that does nothing.

```
function continueSession() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.get("somepage.php").always(continueSession);
    },15*60*1000);
}
continueSession();
```

this should be enough to keep the session going as long as the page is open, and it won't interrupt the user if they're actually using the page at the 15 minute mark.

Comment: is somepage.php a dummy file?

Comment: i think it would need to be a real file, but it doesn't have to return any content or do anything special. It just needs to continue the session in the same way reloading the page would.

Comment: where do I put the continueSession() function call?

Comment: Wherever you want. It only depends on jQuery being included on the page.

Comment: just so you know this did not work. The page gets idle, I have to clear my cookies and cache then load the url to make the page load again.